# run a Jenkins job on another Jenkins instance from the Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to create a Jenkins job that starts other Jenkins jobs. That would be quite easy, because Jenkins Template Project Plugin allows us to create a build step of a type "use builders from another project". However, what makes my situation harder is that I have to start Jenkins jobs on other machines. Is there any standard way to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case you want only to trigger new build of Job You Have plenty of ways to accomplish it

you can use remote access API and Trigger a request to build target job from source Job.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Or you can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin

which is handy in handling server details and other stuff. you shoukld ensure ssh keys shared by both servers.