# Making a jenkins multijob using 2 jenkins jobs reside in two different jenkins servers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a Jenkins multijob using two jenkins jobs reside in  two different jenkins servers. My two jenkins jobs would be **job1** and **job2**. These **job1** and **job2** is located in two different jenkins servers. I want to make a Multijob linking both **job1** and **job2** and also **job2** should be executed only when **job1** successfully completed.

I have search this through online articles but most of them mentioned linking two jobs available within the same jenkins server. But in my case is little different as I mentioned above.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin which can trigger parameterized Build on remote servers.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin

Have a look at the below thread:
[run a Jenkins job on another Jenkins instance from the Jenkins job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439880/run-a-jenkins-job-on-another-jenkins-instance-from-the-jenkins-job)