# Groovy to call a Jenkins pipeline on another Jenkins instance

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

There's a Jenkins pipeline in an instance , say A. I want to call another pipeline from Jenkins instance B in one of the stages in Jenkins instance A. How do I write a groovy for that?
I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439880/run-a-jenkins-job-on-another-jenkins-instance-from-the-jenkins-job) answer but it wasn't useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jenkins plugin [Parameterized Remote Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/)

It's easy to use.

You just need to configure jenkins instance B in manage jenkins. It uses jenkins api in backend.

For groovy help you can check http://${JENKINS_URL}/pipeline-syntax

Comment: For instructions on setting up Parameterized Remote Trigger:
[Global Settings](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_SystemConfiguration.md) and 
[Pipeline Instructions](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_PipelineConfiguration.md)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** You can use HttpBuilder to trigger a remote build. Still you would need the [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) plugin.

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
 
def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters' )
def postBody = [parameter: value] // will be url-encoded
 
http.post( path: '/', body: postBody,
           requestContentType: URLENC ) { resp ->
 
  println "POST Success: ${resp.statusLine}"
  assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 201
}
```

**Option 2:** Or use cURL like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947382/519852

Anyway, in both cases it would only trigger the build and not wait for it to finish nor get its result.